# PHP unexpected '['

Tags: php

I think it's a server configuration error and not a php syntax error.
running Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu) and PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.7

Error :

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/thomas/Documents/myimouto/config/application.php on line 30

here is the code

```
$config->load_files = [
        'app_functions.php',
        'Moebooru/Resizer.php',
        'dtext.php'
    ];

$config->safe_ips = [
        '127.0.0.1',
    '192.168.1.###'
    ];
```

Comment: You are using old version of PHP. upgrade

Comment: which version of PHP you use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check your PHP version first. The short hand form for the  **array** declaration `[]` was only introduced in PHP's version of 5.4 (if am not mistaken). The previous versions only supported the `()` delimiters.

So, I suggest you try changing that line to:

```
$config->safe_ips = array(
     '127.0.0.1',
    '192.168.1.###'
    );
```

or better yet, update to **`PHP  > 5.4`<sub>Yeah..</sub>**