# PHP error unexpected '[' with php 5.3

Tags: php

I can not use a newer PHP version then 5.3 and i get this error message:

```
**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in PATH/product.php on line 17**
```

I founded on this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578298/php-unexpected) that is php version problem, how can i solve this in php 5.3?

The code on this line is exactly:

```
$_productids = [];
```

Comment: Short array syntax was added in php 5.4. Replace it with `array()`.

Comment: Short array syntax was only introduced with PHP 5.4

Comment: replace with `$_productids = array();`

Comment: @Maerlyn you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old version doesn't support this syntax. Update this to:

```
$_productids = array();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use old array syntax:

```
$_productids = array();
```